# Returning an exception with PHP to javascript FETCH API

Tags: javascript, php, api, asynchronous, fetch-api

I am currently coding with javascript and I've hit a wall.
Javascript FETCH api to POST is this:

('form') is my form #ID in html.

```
fetch(URL_TO_POST, {
            method: 'post',
            body: new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

php file:

```
if( !isset($_POST['email'])){
   throw new exception (blabla);
 }
```

URL_TO_POST is like a "validation.php" and inside the code I retrieve some POST informations and do some stuff there. The problem is that I can't throw any exception to the javascript response! Any thoughts on that? Note: I'm not using ajax to post because I'm trying to stay simple and clean with only js code.
Thanks!

Comment: And what do you expect by throwing exception?

Comment: I mean, not throwing an exception exactly, but sending a feedback to user. If the user entered an email in the wrong format, etc.

Comment: Send status code that is not 200.

Comment: Sending a status code that is not 200 is the only way to return errors to the api?

Comment: Send json then. Send xml. Send plain text. Whatever.

Comment: Any idea on how to send a plain text back to javascript ?

Comment: `echo 'MY TEXT';`

Comment: cant see my echoed text.. console.log(response.text); doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript you could use the reject handler to handle invalid data sent to the server:

```
fetch(
  URL_TO_POST, 
  {
    method: 'post',
    body: new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
  }
)
.then(
  function(response) {
    //https://httpstatuses.com/422
    if (response.status === 422) {
      return Promise.reject(response.json());
    }
    //check for other things that could have gone wrong
    return response.json();
  }
).then(
  function(json) {
    console.log("received success json",json)
  }
  ,function(json) {
    console.log("received reject json",json)
  }
)
```

Not clear what you use for PHP but you can provide status code of 422 with some json:

```
http_response_code(422);
echo json_encode(array("error" => "missing field", "field" => "email"));
```